# How to calculate total of all values assigned in JTextFields and ignore the empty ones?

Tags: swing, methods, netbeans-7, jtextfield

Basically, I made lots of JTextFields and I'd like them to be calculated for the total. I want to loop across the the JTextFields calculating the total and ignoring the empty ones. It does not have to be a loop.

I made this simple method assigned to a button.

```
 void groceryDept(){

    int a = Integer.parseInt(appleField.getText());

    int b = Integer.parseInt(bananaField.getText());

    int c = Integer.parseInt(tomatoField.getText());

    int e = Integer.parseInt(potatoField.getText());

    int f = Integer.parseInt(lettuceField.getText());

    int g = Integer.parseInt(cucumberField.getText());

    int h = Integer.parseInt(watermelonField.getText());

    int i = Integer.parseInt(pineappleField.getText());

    int j = Integer.parseInt(celeryField.getText());

    int k = Integer.parseInt(carrotField.getText());

    int total = a+b+c+e+f+g+h+i+j+k;

    totalLabel.setText(String.valueOf(total));

}
```

It only calculates when all JTextFields are filled. I am parsing them because it is made a string initially. If anyone knows how to make the JTextField accept Integers ONLY through netbeans, please let me know!

Oh and I'd also like to have a price that will multiply into the input of whatever quantity the user will input.

Comment: So you want to be able to just get the inputs that are not empty? I assume you are getting a NullPointerException trying to parse the empty fields?

Answer (score 0):

> If anyone knows how to make the JTextField accept Integers ONLY

-> You want to use a JSpinner [image: JSpinnerPanel]